# Drilling into JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am getting back the following dataset from my server

```
{"success":"y","carrier":"Verizon Wireless","isMobile":"true"}
```

and when I try to drill into the json result from my ajax function

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'php/lookup.php',
    data: 'number='+encodeURIComponent(num),
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (j) 
    {

        alert(j);
        alert(j.carrier);

    }
```

I am able to alert the entire JSON string when I do alert(j), but when I do alert(j.carrier) I get an undefined.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dataType: 'json'` instead of `datatype: 'json'`.

JavaScript is case-sensitive, and [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) requires does not recognise lowercase `datatype`.

Answer (score 4):

`datatype` should be `dataType` (note the capital `T`).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `datatype` to `dataType`. You could also have your server code send a header of `Content-type: application/json`, but fixing the parameter should probably be enough.

Comment: This is because without a `dataType`, jQuery uses the MIME type to guess what the `dataType` is :-)

Comment: @Rocket Yup. Never hurts to be too specific. :)